# How to return a list of people in neo4j?

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I am new to neo4j and i am trying to answer a few practice questions. However, i am not getting the syntax and struggling to understand how to return a list of people. The following is the question i am trying to answer:

Assume we have a graph database containing two sets of nodes labelled :Reader and :Book. These nodes are connected with relationships labelled :READ.

Write the Cipher code to list all readers who have read the book with the title "Moby Dick"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This query will get you those readers.

```
MATCH(r:READER)-[:READS]->(b:BOOK{title:"Moby Dick"}
RETURN r
```